# CakePHP 3.4: Pagination with union resultset shows duplicate records

Tags: cakephp, union, pagination

I'm extracting two types of members from a club membership database; I have two custom finder methods to extract these. These finders are working correctly. A third custom finder invokes the other two and uses a Union statement to create a single resultset. The contents of the resultset are correct. However, using Paginate in the index.ctp shows the complete resultset (correctly) and then repeats the contents of the second finder. The union resultset does not contain duplicates. It looks like Paginate is confused by the union results.

**Code from third custom finder:**

```
public function findMembersByBadAddress(Query $query, array $options=[])
{
    // Find members records with bad email or mailing addresses 
    // Specify "mailing" or "email" as the "Address" option to select either bad mailing addresses or bad
    // email addresses

    // Specific fields are retrieved so both resultset have the same number of columns. This allows the 
    // Union to work.
    $fieldsToKeep = ['Members.id','Members.first_name','Members.middle_name',
        'Members.last_name','Members.suffix', 'Members.date_joined'];

    if( $options['Address'] == 'mailing' ) {
        $flag = ['MailingAddresses.is_invalid' => true];
        $contain = ['MailingAddresses'];
    } else {
        $flag = ['EmailAddresses.is_invalid' => true];
        $contain = ['EmailAddresses'];
    }

    $query = $this->find('currentFullMembers');
    $query->contain($contain);
    $query->Select($fieldsToKeep);
    $query->where($flag);
    //Log::write('debug', "Count from MembersTable:Full = " . $query->count());

    $flagQuery2 = $this->find('lifetimeMembers');
    $flagQuery2->contain($contain);
    $flagQuery2->Select($fieldsToKeep);
    $flagQuery2->where($flag);
    //Log::write('debug', "Count from MembersTable:Lifetime = " . $flagQuery2->count());

    $query->unionAll($flagQuery2);
    $query->epilog("ORDER BY Members__last_name ASC, Members__first_name ASC");
    //Log::write('debug', "Count from MembersTable = " . $query->count());

    return $query;
}
```

**From the Controller:**

```
                case ('M'): // bad mailing addresses  DONE
                $query = $this->Members->find('membersByBadAddress', ['Address' => 'mailing']);
                $this->set('reportTitle', 'Bad Mailing Addresses');
                break;
```

...

```
   $this->set('members', $this->paginate($query, ['limit' => $pageLimit]) );
```

**From index.ctp**

```
           <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class='table-condensed'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('id') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('first_name') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('middle_name') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('last_name') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('suffix') ?></th>
                    <?php
                        if( $displayJoinDate ) {
                            echo "<th scope='col'>" . $this->Paginator->sort('Date Joined') . "</th>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    <th scope="col" class="actions"><?= __('Actions') ?></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
        //          Log::write('debug', "Count = " . $members->count());
                     foreach($members as $member) {
                    //   Log::write("debug", $member->first_name . ' ' . $member->last_name);
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $this->Number->format($member->id) . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . h($member->first_name) . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . h($member->middle_name) . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . h($member->last_name) . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . h($member->suffix) . "</td>";
                        if( $displayJoinDate ) {
                           echo "<td>" . h($member->date_joined) . "</td>";
                        }
                        echo '<td class="actions">';
                            echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['action' => 'view', $member->id]);
                            echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $member->id]);
                            echo $this->Html->link(__('Renew'), ['controller' => 'Dues2', 'action' => 'add', $member->id]);
                     //      <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $id], 
                     //             ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $id)]) 
                        echo "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
             }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Is there anyway around this?

**UPDATE**

I suspect the problem is caused by the LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0 after the first SELECT statement and not after the UNION.
Here is the SQL statement as displayed in the SQL log of DebugKit:

```
SELECT
```

Suffixes.suffix AS `Suffixes__suffix` 
FROM 
  suffixes Suffixes

(
  SELECT 
    Members.id AS `Members__id`, 
    Members.first_name AS `Members__first_name`, 
    Members.middle_name AS `Members__middle_name`, 
    Members.last_name AS `Members__last_name`, 
    Members.suffix AS `Members__suffix`, 
    Members.date_joined AS `Members__date_joined` 
  FROM 
    members Members 
    INNER JOIN dues2 Dues2 ON (
      Members.member_type = '1' 
      AND Dues2.payment_category = 2 
      AND Dues2.created >= '2017-10-10 00:00:00' 
      AND Dues2.created <= '2018-12-31 23:59:59' 
      AND Members.id = (Dues2.member_id)
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN members SocialMembers ON (
      SocialMembers.member_type = 2 
      AND Members.id = (SocialMembers.full_member_id)
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN email_addresses EmailAddresses ON Members.id = (EmailAddresses.member_id) 
  WHERE 
    EmailAddresses.is_invalid = 1 
  GROUP BY 
    Members.id 
  ORDER BY 
    Members.last_name ASC, 
    Members.first_name ASC 
  LIMIT 
    20 OFFSET 0
) 
UNION ALL 
  (
    SELECT 
      Members.id AS `Members__id`, 
      Members.first_name AS `Members__first_name`, 
      Members.middle_name AS `Members__middle_name`, 
      Members.last_name AS `Members__last_name`, 
      Members.suffix AS `Members__suffix`, 
      Members.date_joined AS `Members__date_joined` 
    FROM 
      members Members 
      LEFT JOIN members SocialMembers ON (
        SocialMembers.member_type = 2 
        AND Members.id = (SocialMembers.full_member_id)
      ) 
      LEFT JOIN email_addresses EmailAddresses ON Members.id = (EmailAddresses.member_id) 
    WHERE 
      (
        Members.is_deceased = 0 
        AND Members.member_type = 4 
        AND EmailAddresses.is_invalid = 1
      ) 
    ORDER BY 
      Members.last_name ASC, 
      Members.first_name ASC
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  Members__last_name ASC, 
  Members__first_name ASC

Comment: Please share your code otherwise some down vote  your question.

Comment: Thanks @Sehdev, I've added the code

Answer (score 0):

You have to force the distinct mode to the paginate :

```
$this->paginate['YourModel'] = [
    'distinct' => true,
];
```